# writing a better regular expression in the url image extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a regular expression for the url image extension.

I obtain url from body and judge whether there is a image extension in url.

I'd like you to judge if there is a better writing a style

```
def invalid_extension
  urls = URI.extract(body, %w(http https))
  if urls.map { |x| (x.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)/)) }.compact.present?
  errors.add(:body, "Invalid extension")
end
```

Comment: What happens if that `if` is true? your code is not valid because the `if` has no body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to write your own code (assuming that you want to just return if there is a valid image URI):

```
def invalid_extension
  image_extensions = %(jpg jpeg png gif bmp)
  URI.extract(body, %w(http, https)) do |uri|
    return if image_extensions.include? URI(uri).body.split('.').last
  end
  errors.add(:body, "Invalid extension")
end
```

However, your code has some issues:

- What if the `body` contains multiple URIs, some of which are not image URIs? the `URI.extract` method is designed to match **multiple** URIs within a string.
- Not sure what `errors` actually refers to, is this code in a model context or controller context?

Comment: >What if the body contains multiple URIs, some of which are not image URIs? 

make it a link with thumbnail.

>Not sure what errors actually refers to, is this code in a model context or controller context?

model context